# How to show a relationship in the Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I am using Django 2.1 and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to show relationships in the Admin.
I have two Models `Hospital` and `Unit` and a third one is `Exam`. They are set up like this:

- `Hospital` can have many Units and one Unit belongs to one Hospital.
- And the `Exam` model has the exam attributes like exam name and hospital name.

```py
class Hospital(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Unit(models.Model):

    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent_company = models.ForeignKey(
        Hospital, related_name='unit_parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Hospital")


class Exam(models.Model):

    unit_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Hospital, related_name='hospital_pk', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,
                                 null=True, verbose_name="Exam's name")
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exam_name


class CustomExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Exam
    list_display = ('exam_name', 'time', 'alert',
                    'document', 'notes', 'report', 'patients_name', 'unit_name')
    list_filter = ('exam_name', 'time')
    list_select_related = ('unit_name',)
    fieldsets = (
        ("Hospital's Name:", {
            'fields': ('unit_name',)}),
        ('Types of Exams:', {
            'fields': ('exam_name', 'modality', 'model_used')}),
        ("Patient's name:", {
            'fields': ('patients_name',)}),
     )
```

So, in the Exams page in Django Admin I am able to select the Hospital name, however I am not able to select the Unit that belongs to the hospital. I need to select the hospital as well as the unit that belongs to it.
Should I add another `ForeignKey` to Exam, like this:
unit_selected = models.ForeignKey(
Unit, related_name='unit_pk', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

For instance: Hospital: Brookdale University Hospital
Unit: Downtown Unit

What I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbOHU.png)

Comment: What do you see? Can you print the screen? I'd guess that you could do something like `unit_name__name` but it's hard to say without seeing it

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, I just added the screenshot. What I want is to select Hospital and Units white trying to create an exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select the `Unit` in the `Admin`, you need to first add it to the `Exam` model. You have a field called `unit_name`, but you have defined it as a foreign key to the `Hospital` model, not the `Unit` model. If you have a `unit_name` field, you don't really need a separate `hospital` field, since you can easily get it from `unit_name.parent_company`. So you can do this:

```
class Exam(models.Model):

    unit_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Unit, related_name='exams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exam_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,
                                 null=True, verbose_name="Exam's name")
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exam_name
```

For the admin, rather than selecting the hospital and unit separately, the simplest approach, in my opinion, is to include the hospital name as part of the unit name when you select it in the admin, like `Brookdale University Hospital|Downtown Unit`. That way you only need one dropdown field. You can do that like this:

```
from django import forms


class UnitChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "{}|{}".format(obj.parent_company.name, obj.unit_name)


class CustomExamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Exam
    list_display = ('exam_name', 'time', 'alert',
                    'document', 'notes', 'report', 'patients_name', 'get_hospital', 'unit_name')
    list_filter = ('exam_name', 'time')
    list_select_related = ('unit_name__parent_company',)
    fieldsets = (
        ("Hospital's Name:", {
            'fields': ('unit_name',)}),
        ('Types of Exams:', {
            'fields': ('exam_name', 'modality', 'model_used')}),
        ("Patient's name:", {
            'fields': ('patients_name',)}),
     )

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'unit_name':
            return UnitChoiceField(
                queryset=Unit.objects.all().select_related('parent_company').order_by(
                'parent_company.name', 'unit_name'))
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def get_hospital(self, obj):
    #  required to add hospital name to list_display
        return obj.unit_name.parent_company.name           
    get_hospital.short_description = 'Hospital'
```

One other note: the `related_name` in a `ForeignKeyField` is the relation from the foreign model back to the model you are defining. So in the `Unit` model

```
parent_company = models.ForeignKey(
    Hospital, related_name='unit_parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Hospital")
```

should be

```
 parent_company = models.ForeignKey(
    Hospital, related_name='units', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Hospital")
```

Then from the `Hospital` model you can refer to the list of units as `units`.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, Well, I have two apps one called Hospitals, which contains, Hospital and Unit models and the second one called Exam. So, when I test your code in Exams Admin.py I get the error: "'Exam' object has no attribute 'parent_company'. Should I create one big models.py containing Hospitals, Units and Exams?

Comment: I have edited the `UnitChoiceField` class. Try it now.

Comment: Sorry for just getting back to you now. I didn't have Internet access for awhile. That is odd, now I am getting "'str' object has no attribute 'parent_company' ". This is really frustrating, I have been practicing Django for quiet sometime now, and yet I find myself stuck. Thanks evergreen!!

Comment: Sorry for all the errors, Joanny. I should have looked more carefully before I made the previous edit. Unfortunately I can't test the code before posting since I don't have the whole project. I have edited the `UnitChoiceField` class (which was correct to begin with) and also the `get_hospital` method (which is where the original error was). Please try one more time...

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! You have been more than helpful. I didn't know how to use formfield_for_foreignkey method properly until now. Once again, thanks!